How to scan and autowire repositories of an external jar from spring boot application?
I have a spring boot multi-module project where module contains @Repository and @Entity classes .
We create a jar out of this module and add it as a external library in main Spring boot application.
We have added the module jar as a dependency in the pom.xml of main app.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>mymodule-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

We have autowired the repository class of the external jar in main app service class.

Main app has its own repository and entity classes
External app has its own repository and entity classes
We are trying to bring the main app up with the proper bean creation and autowiring them.


Approaches :


@EnableJpaRepositories in main app for its own repository package : external repo bean not created. And error also says Not a managed type: ExternalEntity Class
@EnableJpaRepositories in main app for its own repository package and external package : external repo bean not created. And error also says Not a managed type: ExternalEntity Class
@EnableJpaRepositories in external dep for its own repo package : main repo bean not created
@EnableJpaRepositories in external dep and main app for its own repo package : external repo bean not created. And error also says Not a managed type: ExternalEntity Class
@EnableJpaRepositories in external dep and main app for its own repo package and external package : external repo bean not created. And error also says Not a managed type: ExternalEntity Class
@ComponentScan for base-package which is common like given below. In this case also it failed to create the beans and autowire them.
External repo : com.example.external.repo
Main repo : com.example.myapp.repo
We used : @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.external.entity"), in this case also the bean autowiring did not happen and error was "Not a managed type : ExternalEntity class".

QUESTION : How to create beans and properly get the required dependencies for the autowired respository classes from both main app and external module ?
Configuration
Created a class ExternalApp like below :
@AutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.external")
// Added to create beans for repository autowired in service class.
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.external.repository", considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class NoteAutoConfiguration {
}

This below file is where the above configuration class package.classname is mentioned :
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports


The pattern I've used before is the following:

In external library; Define your beans into @Configuration classes. The important detail is to ensure the class that contains the beans is managed by spring.

@Configuration
public class ConfigClass1 {
    @Bean("SomeClassA-id")
    SomeClassA someClassA(){ ... }
}


In your application, set up dependency from your app to this external module
In your application; add a reference to the configuration classes you made in external library:

//main class
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ ConfigClass1.class, ... })
public class Application{

    public static main(String [] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class ...
    }

}

//spring managed class to reference bean to use in application:
@Component
public class Component1 {
   @Autowire
   @Qualifier("SomeClassA-id")
   private SomeClassA someClassA;

}

More complex / realistic scenario:
If you have many Configuration files (each containing relevant beans) in your external library:
You can make an additional @Configuration class that has the @ComponentScan annotation; such that the argument/s provided to ComponentScan reference the packages of these bean containing Configuration classes. Now in your external module you will have a single configuration class, that references all your relevant beans. You can apply the same pattern above for step 3, and instead reference this single configuration class.

I have added the configuration, I have updated in the query. And still this same issue is happening.
